# Why is `error evaluating code` coming up in Visual Studio Code when starting to debug?

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I have an `error evaluating code` notification coming up when debugging, and the debugging process is always breaking up at a certain point.

Debugging used to work fine before.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution being a WATCH I had set. It said 'error evaluating code' at the end of an expression (out of sight) in the WATCH pane.
After deleting that expresson from the WATCH pane, debugging worked again properly.

I assume it to be a WATCH of an expression I had deleted in the code meanwhile. I can not say for sure as I use the same expression multiple times in my code and could not say which instance the faulty one belonged to.