# 'error evaluating code' when debugging php with Xdebug in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am trying to debug PHP with Xdebug in listening mode in VS Code.

For some commands I receive the unspecific `error evaluating code`, which tells me that something went wrong, but I don't know what. For example, `mkdir($dir_path, 711, true);` sometimes returns this error (when apparently something went wrong), while `file_exists($dir_path);` works (returning true or false). I presume this is a case of `permission denied` for `mkdir()`, but I would expect the error message to tell me about it.

Another example producing the error is by `echo "str";`.

There has been a similar issue [opened up](https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1476) on this, but I don't understand the answer. Even when using semicolons at the end, I receive the error. And `mkdir()` should return true or false.

Version information:

```
PHP Version 7.2.34-26+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Visual Studio Code 1.6.2
Xdebug 3.1.1
```

I have no variables on the watch list, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66522851/why-is-error-evaluating-code-coming-up-in-visual-studio-code-when-starting-to) and [here](https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/192#issuecomment-627837504).

**Edit**

Here the Xdebug log (excerpt):

```
[855784] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="dbgp://stdin" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.2.34-26+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="855784"><engine version="3.1.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[855784] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[855784] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[855784] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n notify_ok -v 1
[855784] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[855784] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n extended_properties -v 1
[855784] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[855784] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t line -f file:///home/myname/path/app/helpers/ImageHelper.php -n 471
[855784] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6" id="693520003" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[855784] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t line -f file:///home/myname/path/app/helpers/ImageHelper.php -n 579
[855784] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="693520004" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[855784] [Step Debug] <- run -i 8
[855784] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="8" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[855784] [Step Debug] <- stop -i 9
[855784] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="9" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>
```

Comment: Make an `xdebug.log` (https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#log) and see what it says? And then add it here.

Comment: Hello Derick. I added `xdebug.log = "/home/myname/somepath/xdebug.log"` and `xdebug.log_level = 7` to /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/99-xdebug.ini and restarted apache, but the log is not created. How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to put it in a directory where your web server can write to, so `/tmp/` or `/var/log` are the directories to use.

Comment: I tried with these directories, but I still do not get a log..

Comment: What was the value of `xdebug.log` ? Did you include the file name?

Comment: I now managed to receive some log and included it in my question. I still don't understand when something is logged though, most of the time it doesn't write anything if I delete the log file (having Xdebug in listening mode, producing an error, stopping and resuming at a breakpoint).

Comment: You'll need to find the "eval -i" command in the log, and show the command and `<response` for that.

Comment: There are no "eval -i" and "<response" in the log. However, for the moment I did not run into the error which I described here, as I solved the problem in this concrete case. I will come back here once I receive the error again.